# Finding an automorphism of the Riemann sphere that sends the branch points of the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$ to $(0, \infty, -1, 1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions, riemann-sphere

I’ve read on my lecture notes that we can find an automorphism of the Riemann sphere that sends the branch points of the Weierstrass elliptic function over the complex torus $X=\mathbb{C} / {\mathbb{Z}[i]}$ (that is, the image by $\wp$ of its four ramification points) to a given set of four points.

More concretely, I know that the ramification points of $\wp$ are $e_0=\pi(0)$, $e_1=\pi(i/2)$, $e_2=\pi(1/2)$, $e_3=\pi((1+i)/2)$ (where $\pi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the canonical projection), and according to the lecture notes there exists an automorphism $\phi: \hat{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}} $ such that $\phi \circ (\wp(e_1),\wp(e_2),\wp(e_3),\wp(e_0))= (0,\infty,1,-1)$.

I’ve noticed that since $\wp(iz)=-\wp(z)$, we have $\wp(e_3)=0$ and $\wp(e_1)=-\wp(e_2)$. I also know that $\wp(e_0)=\infty$. So I’m looking for an automorphism $\phi: \hat{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}} $ such that $\phi \circ (\wp(e_1),-\wp(e_1),0,\infty) = (0,\infty,1,-1)$.

I know automorphisms of the Riemann sphere are of the form $z \rightarrow \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, and I’ve tried solving the system but I didn’t find a solution. Did I go wrong somewhere, or could there be an error in the problem statement? It would make more sense to me if the image of the four points by $\wp$ were $(1,-1,0,\infty)$ instead of $(0,\infty,1,-1)$, because then I guess the automorphism could be given by $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=\wp(e_1)$, $d=0$.

Comment: Basically, you're asking whether there exists a Mobius transformation that maps a given tuple of 4 points to another tuple of 4 points? Surely the answer is no? You can do this for 3 points, but not for 4 points.

Comment: Could you please check to see if you interpreted your lecture notes correctly? I suspect what your notes really said is that, given any four points on $\hat C$, there exists a cubic elliptic curve whose branch points are those 4 points. I'm happy to elaborate if you don't mind double checking your notes.

Comment: @KennyWong Thank you. What they say exactly is that you can compose $\wp$ with a suitable automorphism of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ (that we call $\phi$) such that $p:=\phi \circ \wp$ verifies $(p(e_1),p(e_2),p(e_3),p(e_0)=(0,\infty,1,-1)$.

Comment: $e_1,e_2, e_3$ do [usually denote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function#The_constants_e1,_e2_and_e3) the *values* of the $\wp$ function at the half-periods.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it seems you’re right… I was using the notation that appears in my lecture notes though, where they’re defined like in my question. Not sure why they used a different notation.

Comment: @tjdominic Ah I should have read your question more carefully. You're specifically dealing with the _square_ torus. Apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Möbius transformation $T$ is uniquely determined by the images $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ at three distinct points $(z_1, z_2, z_3)$. $T$ maps a fourth point $z_4$  to $w_4$ if and only if the [*cross ratios*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio)
$$
 (z_1, z_2, z_3,z_4) = (w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4)
$$
are equal, and that is the case for these particular values:
$$
 (\wp(e_1), \wp(e_2), \wp(e_3), \wp(e_0)) = (\wp(e_1), -\wp(e_1), 0, \infty ) = -1 = (0, \infty, 1, -1) \, .
$$

Concretely:
$$
 \phi(z) = \frac{z-\wp(e_1)}{z-\wp(e_2)} \cdot \frac{\wp(e_3)-\wp(e_2)}{\wp(e_3)-\wp(e_1)}
$$
is the (unique) Möbius transformation which maps $\wp(e_3), \wp(e_1), \wp(e_2)$ to $1, 0, \infty$, respectively. Here we have $\wp(e_3) = 0$ and $\wp(e_1) = -\wp(e_2)$, so that it simplifies to
$$
 \phi(z) = -\frac{z-\wp(e_1)}{z+\wp(e_1)} \, .
$$
Then $\phi(\wp(e_0)) = \phi(\infty) = -1$, so that $\phi$ has the desired properties.